# How would I write this as an operator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics

I hav the following Hamilitonian:

$$ H \propto   \frac{3(\mathbf{I}\cdot\mathbf{J})^2 + \frac{3}{2}(\mathbf{I}\cdot\mathbf{J}) -\mathbf{I}^2*\mathbf{J}^2}{2I(2I-1)J(2J-1)}, $$

which want to diagonalise, i.e. I found the matrix forms of $\mathbf{I}$, $\mathbf{L}$ and $\mathbf{S}$ and brute-forcing it.

How would I write the denominator in terms of the operators?

I can still work with this but I would need to input the values of $I$ and $J$ by hand, $J$ being different for $P_{1/2}$ and $P_{3/2}$ states though.

Definitions of $J$ and $I$ for those who do not know:

$ \mathbf{J}^2 |J,I\rangle = J(J+1)|J,I\rangle $,

$ \mathbf{I}^2 |J,I\rangle = I(I+1)|J,I\rangle $,

assuming $\hbar = 1$.

Comment: So... why is there a d̶o̶t̶ ̶p̶r̶o̶d̶u̶c̶t̶ meaningless $*$ symbol between the two scalars $I^2=\mathbf I^2$ and $J^2=\mathbf J^2$?

Comment: Your question 'How would I write the denominator in terms of the operators?' makes very little sense. The form assumes that you're already in an eigenstate of both $\mathbf J^2$ and $\mathbf I^2$, so it already is in terms of the operators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to analyze a hamiltonian of the form
$$ H \propto   \frac{3(\mathbf{I}\cdot\mathbf{J})^2 + \frac{3}{2}(\mathbf{I}\cdot\mathbf{J}) -{I}^2{J}^2}{2I(2I-1)J(2J-1)}, $$
the key insight is that for any two angular momenta $\mathbf I$ and $\mathbf J$ whose components commute you have
$$(\mathbf I+\mathbf J)^2 = I^2 +2\mathbf I\cdot\mathbf J +J^2$$
and therefore
$$\mathbf I\cdot\mathbf J = \frac{(\mathbf I+\mathbf J)^2 - I^2 -J^2}{2}.$$
This means that in the subspaces where $(\mathbf I+\mathbf J)^2$ is constant, which you find via the usual Clebsch-Gordan procedure for the addition of quantum mechanical angular momenta, the inner product $\mathbf I\cdot\mathbf J$ is also a constant operator.

That said, it's important to note that this hamiltonian makes no sense for $J=1/2$, which is one of the states you indicate ($P_{1/2}$, though you give no indication of what $\mathbf I$ is in your model or how you're handling $\mathbf L$), so you need to proceed with caution.

---

It also seems, from your comments, that you've got some fixed nuclear spin $I$, and that you've formed $J$ out of an addition of an orbital and a spin angular momentum for the electronic degrees of freedom, such as e.g. a single electron in a $P$ state, which will give you a subspace of $J=1/2$ of dimension $2$, and one with $J=3/2$ of dimension $4$. It seems that you're confused as to how you would write your hamiltonian as a matrix in that basis.

The truth is that you don't really need to, because your analysis is already decoupled into the different $J$ subspaces and they won't mix again unless you introduce some really ugly hamiltonian. However, if you do insist on turning a hamiltonian like e.g.
$$ H = \frac{J_z}{J(J+1)}, $$
say, on a basis that includes multiple $J$ representations, like e.g. the basis from before,
$$\left\{
\left|\frac12,\frac12\right>, \left|\frac12,-\frac12\right>, \left|\frac32,\frac32\right>, \left|\frac32,\frac12\right>, \left|\frac32,-\frac12\right>, \left|\frac32,-\frac32\right>
\right\},$$
then you simply concatenate the two matrices as blocks:
$$
H=
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\frac12}{\frac12\left(\frac12+1\right)} & 0  \\
0& \frac{-\frac12}{\frac12\left(\frac12+1\right)} \\
&&\frac{\frac32}{\frac32\left(\frac32+1\right)} &0&0&0\\
&&0&\frac{\frac12}{\frac32\left(\frac32+1\right)} &0&0\\
&&0&0&\frac{-\frac12}{\frac32\left(\frac32+1\right)} &0 \\
&&0&0&0&\frac{-\frac32}{\frac32\left(\frac32+1\right)}
\end{pmatrix},
$$
where the blank spaces are also zeroes but I'm leaving them out to emphasize the block nature of the matrix.

Of course, for your full hamiltonian, you will need to make an even bigger matrix: your hamiltonian contains terms proportional to e.g. $I_z J_z$, where you've got two copies of the above matrix multiplied by $I_z=\pm\frac12$. It also contains terms like $I_xJ_x$, where the $I_x$ term needs to be handled correctly via the usual tensor-product structure, and the $J_x$ term is not diagonal within each fixed-$J$ subspace: you will have two non-diagonal blocks for the matrix of e.g. $H=J_x/(J(J+1))$, but the blanks will still be zero.

Comment: Thanks,

Is $\mathbf{I}^2\mathbf{J}^2 |J,I\rangle$ the same as $I^2 J^2 |J,I\rangle$?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: So I guessed I was writing in bold to keep in mind it's an operator and not just the square of the quantum number $J$ or $I$.

Basically I construct the $\mathbf{L}$ and $\mathbf{S}$ matrices starting from the $L$ and $S$ quantum numbers. Then I sum them to get $\mathbf{J}$. So I actually don't know $J$. Hence my desire to write the denominator in terms of a matrix operator instead of a quantum number.

Comment: If you want to emphasize it's an operator, use hats. If you've summed them to get $J$, then you do know $\mathbf J$, and if you've formed $J$ out of an $L$ and an $S$ component then the different $J$s will make $\hat{J}$ a diagonal matrix on the $\hat{J}$ eigenbasis. (Unless you're being wrongheaded and you want it in the $L,L_z,S,S_z$ basis, that is.)

Comment: @SuperCiocia See edited answer; I think this addresses your core question.